# выполнение php запроса через terminal linux

Tags: php, linux, terminal

В чем разница между выполнением этих двух команд из консоли:

```
php -f cron/cron-minute.php force
```

и следующая

```
php -f cron/cron-minute.php
```

**UPD** вот код внутри

```
<?php

$force = isset($argv[1]);

$pidFile = __FILE__.'.pid';
$pidDate = @file_get_contents($pidFile);
if (!$force) {
    if ($pidDate > date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() - 3600)) {
        print "\n\nProcess already running...\n\n";
        exit();
    }
}

file_put_contents($pidFile, date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), LOCK_EX);

require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../packages/Engine/include.2.6.php');

Machine::Get()->eErrorReporting();

if ($force) {
    Loader::Get()->setMode('debug', true);
}

// генерируем событие
try {
    $event = Events::Get()->generateEvent('afterCronHour');

    if ($force) {
        // показываем что будем запускать
        $a = $event->getObserversArray();
        foreach ($a as $object) {
            print 'Observer '.get_class($object)."\n";
        }
    }

    $event->notify();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print $e;
}

unlink($pidFile);

print "\n\ndone.\n\n";
```

Comment: Надо посмотреть исходный код этого `cron-minute.php` или описание. Что это за продукт? Аргумент "force" передаётся в php скрипт и [обрабатывается](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.argv.php) там.

Comment: не видно что-ли `if ($force) { ...  }`?

Comment: сразу не понял что $argv[1]  берет force как аргумент из командной строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если указан любой аргумент (не обязательно именно "force"), то скрипт попытается запустить задачи в любом случае, даже если те уже были запущены менее часа назад. Кроме того, будет включён режим отладки (debug).

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста что вы имеете ввиду режим отладки debug?

Comment: Понятия не имею, это надо смотреть, что за класс `Loader` у вас там упомянут:

    Loader::Get()->setMode('debug', true);